# Use of GPS chipset

Tags: gps

I'm new to the world of GPS. Please help me understand the following:

1) Why GPS chip is required? If the GPS antenna is enough to transmit and receive data, any normal processor could do the decoding of the received GPS data.

2) Does NaviLink 6.0 has its own GPS stack? Doesn't Android has its own GPS stack?

3) NaviLink 6.0 integrates A-GPS, Bluetooth 2.1, FM Tx/Rx on a single chip. Why do you require a chip for bluetooth for FM and Bluetooth? Is FM antenna not enough? Is a separate chip required for Bluetooth too?

Comment: Is this a software development question? Sounds more like a hardware question, so I'm not sure whether this site is the best place to ask this question.

Answer (score 3):

it's possible, and it's called "Software GPS" (there is even an open source project)
however, the CPU resources required are really big, and therefore its not really an option for hand-held mobile devices.
also, the sampling rate need to be very high, ad you need A/D converter, which also complicate things